Change perl version in git installation in Amazon Linux 2023
I am working Amazon Linux 2023 as a base image in Docker, there my requirement is to install git.
When I am installing git via yum install git, git installation is doing perl 5.32 installation. when I am pushing my docker image to ECR it is raising perl 5.32 related vulnerabilities, but those vulnerabilities can be fixed with perl 5.40 version. Is there a way to skip perl 5.32 and take perl 5.40 for git.

What you can do is install desired Perl version before installing git.
Then install git without any dependencies. To install git without weak dependencies you can use this command,
yum install --setopt=install_weak_deps=False git

